# I cannot launch the Steam game Snow

Tags: steam

The Steam game Snow is stuck on “Preparing to launch” for me; reinstalling the game did not fix the issue. I’m new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Please choose a more appropriate title/tag which describes your problem.

Comment: Its a `...Steam Early Access...` game, meaning bugs are to be expected.

Comment: Also, is your problem "`My game freezes when I try to launch a multiplayer session.`"?

Comment: @MarkKirby. Why did you roll back my improvements to the question? It now has ugly unnecessary code formatting, a comma splice, and a lowecase "ubuntu". Also, it now has a very poor title.

Comment: I am not sure @TRiG it was a while ago, I can't see anything really wrong with your edit so I reverted it, seems to have been a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

[Snow The Game](http://www.snowthegame.com), is a [Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/244930) `Early Access Game`, meaning not a finished product. So bugs are to be expected.

Also, the [snow - FAQ](http://www.snowthegame.com/faq/) says there is a problem with multiplayer: "`My game freezes when I try to launch a multiplayer session.`", and their response is:

> "Just wait a few moment and you will eventually be joining the session. We are currently working on a fix to get you in the game instantly." - [snow - FAQ](http://www.snowthegame.com/faq/)

---

With Alpha games/software there is - usually - nothing we can do, but tell you to update, update, update your software to the latest version!

Comment: But when will be SNOW The Game relised like other games for example: Robocraft, Counter Strike: Global Offensive, etc. ? If you know when, and i will be still unable to launch it tell me the solution THANKS